# Get First Sentence with Regex (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've created a regular expression for JavaScript that's supposed to "some what smartly" get the first sentence from a string of text/sentences. I used RegExr to create and test it:

https://regexr.com/3uhoj

However, when I actually implement that regular expression:

`/.*(.)(?=\s[A-Z])/g`

In my JavaScript code I'm using split and I'm getting *everything but* the first sentence. Here's the output:

`[ '', '.', ' Saturday, troopers got a report that […]' ]`

If any RegEx masters see the error in my ways, and/or have any tips or solutions, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

PS: Yes, I've already searched for this...

Comment: In your research what did you find? I think you will find people on StackOverflow are hesitant to help people that don't provide samples of what they have attempted.

Comment: Would be good to post the string you are testing, and the javascript snippet here directly, not just on external link.

Comment: Show your javascript code,

Comment: change `.*(.)` to `(.*?\.)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. While my code was available as an external link, in the future I'll make sure to include it inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```js
const regex = /.*?(\.)(?=\s[A-Z])/;
const str = `© 2018 Telegraph Publishing LLC Four area men between the ages of 18 and 20 were arrested early this morning on a variety of charges in an overnight burglary at the Tater Hill Golf Course in Windham. According to a Vermont State Police press release, at about 2:30 a.m. Saturday, troopers got a report that [&#8230;]`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
console.log(m[0]);
}
```

I use a **lazy** regex match **without the `g` flag** to only retrieve the first result.

Or go with a negated character class as it is more efficient: `/^[^.]+\.(?= [A-Z])/`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the regular expression help. :)